# Possible to call a managed DLL from unmanaged C++?

Tags: .net, c++, interop

Is it possible to call CLR DLL (one for example which is made with C#) from unmanaged C++ code?

I need a DLL that is not managed to call into it somehow, maybe even via some proxy C++ process that is built with C++ / CLI?

Comment: You can wrap that managed dll into an executable which is a console app and takes command line arguments, while spits out its result to the `stdout`. You can then call it as you would any other exe. Not ideal, but might work. I hope you are not using multiple threads, because I do not know if this will work then.

Comment: You gave the answer yourself.  Write a proxy in C++/CLI (or C++.Net or managed C++ or how it's being called today), then call this proxy from your unmanaged C++ code.

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058897/can-c-cli-be-used-to-call-net-code-from-native-c-applications

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The CLR DLL would have to be built as a COM visible assembly.
If you have control of the C#, it's a simple rebuild, otherwise, is pretty much impossible to use it directly.

Comment: Added "...to use it directly." Otherwise the meaning was wrong, sorry.

Comment: @SWeko: There is always Reverse PInvoke. So it is not impossible.

Comment: AFAIK, to use reverse PInvoke, you still need access to the C# code to set delegates and calling conventions (have never used it, so I can't say from experience)

Answer (score 5):

@SWeko gave you the best answer if you can modify the original DLL and your unmanaged code can rely on having access to a COM apartment (either its own thread with `::CoInitialize()` called or the calling thread of the unmanaged code has a consistent apartment).

If that's not the case, then the best solution is to create a "managed" C++ DLL as a wrapper on the managed C# assembly.  It's called C++/CLI.   You can expose unmanaged C API operations and inside the implementation of those, delegate to the managed API's.  It works pretty well and unlike calling COM API's, there are no thread affinity issues.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure it fits, but perhaps "Reverse PInvoke" is an option.

If you can first call from your C# to your C++ then you can provide a .net delegate to the C++ where it is able to be used as a function pointer.  You can then call from your C++ to C# using that function pointer.

```
public delegate int Read(int target);
[DllImport("yourC++.dll")]
static extern void RegisterRead(Read x);
Read m_Read = new Read(yourClass.Read);

RegisterRead(m_Read);
```

There can be some tricks with the GC collecting the delegate early, whatever class has the delegate may need to be pinned if it is not just used immediatly in `RegisterRead`