# Assertion on AfxInitExtensionModule when trying to use C++/CLI

Tags: dll, mfc, c++-cli

I have a need to call some C# code from a native C++ class library. The class library uses MFC in a shared dll. Thanks to [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058897/can-c-cli-be-used-to-call-net-code-from-native-c-applications?rq=1), I recently learned that it is possible to compile only selected files with the /clr option. That's great, it seemed like a clean approach, both from a design perspective as well as from a practical point of view, since the minimal rebuild and precompiled headers functionality is incompatible with /clr.

So I went ahead and added a new C++ class, set the /clr option and wrote some code to call into a .Net dll. So far so good, everyting compiles and even Intellisense works occassionaly. But at runtime I run into problems. When I use the class library from a unit test project, I get an assertion.

I get no stack trace, but the assertion is triggered in the mfc dll (mfc120d.dll in my case) in
dllmodul.cpp in function InternalDllMain at this line

```
VERIFY(AfxInitExtensionModule(controlDLL, hInstance));
```

This happens on startup, before any testcases are run and before any calls to .Net code. Everything works fine when I link the library from an MFC application.

What's going on and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had accidentally written

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

in my C++/CLI .cpp file. Power of habit, I guess. Removing the include fixes the problem.