# Working of an N-tier application

Tags: c#, c++, qt

How does an N-tier application works if some layer is written in one language and other layer is written in another language? How does a compiler works in such a situation? Can I use qt C++ to make gui with logic layer written in C#?

Edit: Suppose a desktop application is to be built with mvc pattern. I was thinking that if its gui(the view) is written in qt then what programming language could be used to make the controller? What language can 'accelerate' processing of inputs from ui?

Comment: Why would you want to create the GUI in Qt? why not use WPF or WinForms?

Comment: Off cause you can. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058897/can-c-cli-be-used-to-call-net-code-from-native-c-applications

Comment: Generally, some languages and libraries do interface to others, and some do not. For example (quite another than your own example), you can write C code for use in python. In the case of compiled languages, you still use one specific compiler for each language. In rare cases, you can arrange with tricky use of comments that a single source code file contains code in several languages.

Comment: thanks for the quick replies. I had read somewhere that  QT framework is a great tool for creating GUIs.

Comment: @amogh Even if it is, is it really worth the added complexity that it will involve?